# Routing question

Tags: routing, subnet, networking

Let’s say I have router A and B and a subnet 192.168.10.0/24. Can I use part of that subnet as a connector between router A and router B (ie. 192.168.10.0/30, .1 on A and .2 on B) and have a route 192.168.10.0/24 on A via 192.168.10.2 on B. Will I be able to use the rest of the 192.168.10.0/24 on router B LAN?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the same networks on two routers (without tricks like NAT). The purpose of routers is to route between *different* networks.

You can use a part of the /24 on router A, another part for the routing link, and a third part on router B but that means you have to subnet your /24 in 3 smaller networks.
Since IP addresses are really binary, subneting works on power of 2 boundaries.

So you no longer have a /24 but at best a /25 subnet (126 addresses, including the router address), a /26 subnet (62 address, including the router address) and a /31 subnet (2 addresses - special case for inter router links, see [rfc3021](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3021))

- Router A: 192.168.10.0/25 network
- Router A to router B link: 192.168.10.254/31 network
- Router B: 192.168.10.128/26 network

The reason you have to use /26 and not /25 on router B is that the interconnection link network, 192.168.10.254/31 is a subnet of 192.168.10.128/25, so it would overlap. You could use an unumbered interface though (router vendor dependent) and have two /25.

Comment: ... or use a completely unrelated subnet between routers A and B, like 172.31.255.0/31. That subnet doesn't need to be visible to end nodes on the "outer" subnets.